# Migrating U2F to WebAuthn in PHP

Tags: php, webauthn, fido-u2f, yubikey

Since chrome is not going to support U2F anymore, I've been tasked with migrating our authentication to WebAuthn for Yubikeys.

We were using https://github.com/Samyoul/U2F-php-server and I've found https://github.com/lbuchs/WebAuthn to replace it with, though I'm open to suggestions because lbuchs/WebAuthn's documentation is lacking.

My question is, do you know know of any tutorials to migrate over in PHP or is it best I just start from scratch? The code does not seem comparable at all, so I'm honestly not sure where to start.

Thanks!